# Can I canonicalize a hostname with dig?

Tags: networking, dns, command-line-interface, dig

My reading of `dig`'s manpage isn't answering this question.  Is there a set of command-line options to `dig` such that I can type

`dig $WHATEVER my-aname.example.com`

and have it do a forward lookup for that host's IP and then have it reverse-resolve that IP to the server's canonical name(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a single lookup.  In any event the definition of a canonical hostname is not as well defined as you would need.

For example, the right-hand side of a `CNAME` record was originally *supposed* to point to a canonical name, but often doesn't (so-called "CNAME chaining").

An IP address can also have multiple PTR records, there's no requirement that there be one (singular) canonical name for an IP address.

Comment: Edited question to reflect that.  I'm not trying to use the information programmatically, I'm just looking at the output, so I don't really need a single canonical name, just the usual output of the reverse-resolve.  But I hadn't known that IPs could have multiple PTR records -- thanks!